# Buttons not positioning themselves right on runtime

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

So, I am making a war game where I also needed UI buttons on top of the screen that will spawn the players troops from the base, but upon runtime, the buttons place themselves where I am not expecting them to be. This is what happens:

[image: Before Runtime]

So this is how I placed them and expected how they should show on runtime.

[image: After Runtime]

And this is what happens when I run the game.

They do still follow the camera for player view but the buttons are not where they supposed to be. What am I completely missing here? Here is the code I made.

```
public class CameraMovement : MonoBehaviour
```

{

```
public float CameraSpeed;
[SerializeField]
public GameObject[] ButtonTest;

private void Update()
{
    float CameraMovement = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

    Vector3 Movement = new Vector3(CameraMovement * CameraSpeed * Time.deltaTime,0,-10);
    transform.Translate(Movement);

    transform.position = new Vector3(Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.x, -16.5f, 16.5f),0,-10);


    Follow();

}

private void Follow()
{
    foreach (GameObject Buttons in ButtonTest)
    {
        Vector3 NewPositions = Buttons.transform.position;
        Vector3 ButtonsPosition = new Vector3(transform.position.x, NewPositions.y, NewPositions.z);
        Buttons.transform.position = ButtonsPosition;
        Debug.Log("position is " + Buttons.transform.position);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `Vector3 ButtonsPosition = new Vector3(transform.position.x, NewPositions.y, NewPositions.z);` you are passing the same `x` position to the transform component. For it to appear besides each other, you will have to add some offset depending on the index of the item. Or try one of the `Layout Group` components of Unity

Comment: I see, that is informative, will try it out, thank you.

Comment: Why not simply use a `HorizontalLayoutGroup`?

Comment: I'm actually trying that at the moment, been experimenting and mixing some stuff until I get satisfactory results, thank you so much for this.